# python regex lookahead and negative lookahead

Tags: python, regex, regex-negation

I am trying to extract messages on my git commit message.

With the code below:

```
import sys, os, re
alpsym = '[A-Za-z_-]'
num = '[0-9]'
ticket = '(?:ticket|issue|bug[: ]?)'
actions = '(?:re|close|closes|closed|fix|fixes|fixed?)'
msg = "testing re #119 , close ticket:#120, fixed mygroup:#119, close #132, fixes mytools:#131"
result = r'(?p<a>(?:%s*)).?(?p<b>(?!%s)|(?:%s*)).?(?p<c>(?:#|%s)%s+).?' % (actions,actions,alpsym,ticket,num)
```

with result:

```
[('', 're', '#119'),
('close', 'ticket', '#120'),
('fixed', 'mygroup', '#119'),
('', 'close', '#132'),
('fixes', 'mytools', '#131')]
```

But I want the result to be:

```
[('re', '', '#119'),
('close', '', '#120'),
('fixed', 'mygroup', '#119'),
('close', '', '#132'),
('fixes', 'mytools', '#131')]
```

Kindly help me achieve the result above.

Answer (score 1):

```
x="testing re #119 , close ticket:#120, fixed mygroup:#119, close #132, fixes mytools:#131"
k=re.split("\s*,\s*",x)
print [re.split("\s+|:",i) for i in k]
```

It is much easier to `split` and then play with it.

Output:`[['testing', 're', '#119'], ['close', 'ticket', '#120'], ['fixed', 'mygroup', '#119'], ['close', '#132'], ['fixes', 'mytools', '#131']]`

Now you can easily remove ,add or do anything you want.

Comment: thanks. I want to have it group like (<action>,<environment>,<ticket>). If there is no value in the msg it should be empty on the result just like what I desired as an output. The comma is just optional.

Comment: @Austin the first line of output...where has `testing` gone?

Comment: testing is not part of the action. Actions were defined in the action variable.